# PDF opens in Acrobat X but not programatically in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, pdf

I've written an interface with a 3rd party web service in VB.NET.  The final step in that interface involves the 3rd party delivering to us (as a stream) a PDF document.  After streaming is complete I save a copy of the PDF on our servers, so that our users can view the PDF by clicking on a link in our system.  The PDF opens fine in Acrobat X, but when I try to open it programatically I an error saying that "the file is damaged and could not be repaired".  I can also open the file in IE just fine, with no issues, and the same code that  displays this PDF works just fine on lots of other existing PDFs that predate the 3rd party interface.

I have emptied out temporary internet files as suggested in some posts I saw online.  I also opened the PDF in Notepad++ and the %PDF tag is first, and the %%EOF tag is last, so there's certainly no corruption visible in the document source that I can see.  Below is the (very standard) code we use to open PDFs into a separate browser instance on our site:

```
PDFFile = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & Request.QueryString("LetterPath") & Request.QueryString("Letter") 
Response.Clear()
Response.ClearHeaders()
Response.BufferOutput = True
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
Response.WriteFile(PDFFile)
Response.Flush()
```

Anyone dealt with this before or have any ideas?

Comment: Yep, that did it....thanks!  There actually were Response.End statements in the code but they were commented out.  Uncommented them and all is good.  Not sure why it was never an issue on any of our other PDFs.  Thanks Magnus!

Comment: Great, I'll post it as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a `Response.End()` should do it.